# Показ видео при загрузке страницы

Tags: jquery, opera

```html
                <iframe class="video-test"  frameborder="0" width="480px" height="280px"  srcdoc="<style>html, body, a, img {display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}</style><a href='http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/3jT_q7dt-cM'><img src='//img.youtube.com/vi/3jT_q7dt-cM/maxresdefault.jpg' srcset='//img.youtube.com/vi/3jT_q7dt-cM/mqdefault.jpg 320w, //img.youtube.com/vi/3jT_q7dt-cM/hqdefault.jpg 480w, //img.youtube.com/vi/3jT_q7dt-cM/maxresdefault.jpg 1307w'></a>" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

```js
$('.video-test').each(function(){
    $(this).mousedown();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Во время загрузки стоят статическая картинка. При загрузке страницы происходит клик и появляется само видео. В гугле и хроме работает нормально. Но в опере остается статическая картинка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите в консоли ошибка:

> *Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://example.com' was loaded over HTTPS,
>   but requested an insecure resource
>   'http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/3jT_q7dt-cM'. **This request has
>   been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS**.*

Браузер заблокировал запрос по протоколу `http://`, так как этот протокол устарел и небезопасен. Используйте `https://`

*http**s**://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/3jT_q7dt-cM*